# Como decodificar trama que envía GPS Concox AT4

Tags: c#, gps, netcore

Tengo un GPS de la marca Concox modelo AT4

Ya lo tengo configurado mediante SMS al gps para que me envie data a un servidor público por el puerto 10000. El servidor lo he levantando con socket desde c#

Sin embargo cuando me llega la data al parecer llega encriptada

Añado 3 ejemplos.

xxST??Xx0IPK
xxST??Xx0IA?
xxST??Xx0IsY

Si alguien sabe como descencriptar aquello le agradecería ya que necesito la latitud y longutud